# JAVA: Configure logback in standalone apps

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have a Java standalone app. with a main method, with these 2 imports:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

and

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PecadorDeLaPradera.class);
```

In the same folder I also have a `logback.xml` but I don't know how to tell the program that uses the `logback.xml` to config the log

I couldn't find any class similar to `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator`

I have this `logback.xml` in the same folder of the Java class I am running:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <!-- trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal -->
    <timestamp key="myTimestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH-mm-ss.SSS"/>  


    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <!-- To enable JMX Management -->
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"}  [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>pecador.log</file> 

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>handler.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>             
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>3</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <!-- <logger name="org.springframework.orm.jpa"     level="debug" /> -->    
    <logger name="com.calzada.pecador"  level="debug" />


    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I also run the appl. with Program arguments:

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/Users/calzada/Dev/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/myApp/src/com/calzada/pecador/logback.xml
```

and I got this error:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name -Dlogback.configurationFile=/Users/nullpointer/Development/J2EE/eclipseWSJ2EE/myApp/src/com/calzada/pecador/logback.xml, locale en_ES
```

The library used is `logback-classic-1.2.3.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how logback configures itself:

> Logback tries to find a file called `logback-test.xml` in the classpath.
>
> If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called `logback.groovy` in the classpath.
>
> If no such file is found, it checks for the file `logback.xml` in the classpath.
>
> If no such file is found, service-provider loading facility (introduced in JDK 1.6) is used to resolve the implementation of `com.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator` interface by looking up the file `META-INF\services\ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator` in the class path. Its contents should specify the fully qualified class name of the desired Configurator implementation.
>
> If none of the above succeeds, logback configures itself automatically using the `BasicConfigurator` which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

You can also point Logback at a specific configuration file using the system parameter `logback.configurationFile`. From the docs:

> You may specify the location of the default configuration file with a system property named "logback.configurationFile". The value of this property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path to a file external to the application.
>
> `java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1`

All the above taken from the [docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).

According to your question you have a `logback.xml` but this file is in the "same folder" as your class. Unless your class is in the root package this means that `logback.xml` is not in the root of the classpath so Logback will not discover it. In order for Logback to configure itself from this file you can do one of the following:

- Place your logback.xml in the root of your classpath (for a Maven project this is as simple as copying `logback.xml` to `src/main/resources`)
- Run your Java program with `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/logback.xml`